# Random variable distribution. Reposted

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

$X$ has distribution $B (30, 0.6)$. Find $P(X \geq 16)$.

I know how to find $2$ or $3$ numbers where you use combinations and simply add probabilities for each variable. But this value includes $14$ variables and I don't think it wants me to do them all separately.

$Y$ has distribution $B(4, 0.7)$. Three values are chosen at random. Find the probability that their total is $10$.

I don't know the method for this type of question.

Comment: For first question, are you expected to approximate the probability using normal distribution? The distribution of $X$ is approximately normal, with the same mean and variance as the $B$, i.e. $$X'\sim N[30\times.6, 30\times.6\times(1-.6)].$$ Then find (or look up) the probability $P(X'\ge15.5)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first question, are you expected to approximate the probability using normal distribution? The distribution of $X$ is approximately normal, with the same mean and variance as the $B$, i.e. $$X'\sim N[30\times.6, 30\times.6\times(1-.6)].$$ Then find (or look up) the probability $P(X'\ge15.5)$.

**More**: When $n$ is large enough and $p$ is not close to $0$ nor $1$, binomial distribution can be approximated by a normal distribution. (For the criteria of "enough" see [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation))

If $X\sim B(n,p)$, then the mean of $X$ is $np$ and the variance of $X$ is $np(1-p)$. This pair of value can be supplied to form an approximate normal distribution:

$$X'\sim N\left(\mu=np, \sigma^2 = np(1-p)\right)$$

Then, with a slight continuity correction (binomial distribution is discrete but normal distribution is continuous), the required probability can be found as

$$P(X\ge16)\approx P(X'\ge15.5)=P\left(Z\ge\frac{15.5-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}\right)$$

This is usually found by looking up $Z$-table or numerical integration.

---

If $Y_1+Y_2+Y_3=10$, then the possible values of the $Y_i$'s are
$$(2,4,4),(3,3,4),(3,4,3),(4,2,4),(4,3,3),(4,4,2)$$
Find the probability of each case, and sum.

Comment: why $Y_i \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Could you rewrite equation for the first part for dummies?

Comment: @Ant Because a binomial distribution only gives non-negative integers

Comment: @user154346 modified

Comment: Unfortunately 15.5-18 makes the whole thing negative. So as I square it to get positive outcome, numbers still don't seem quite right. Answer provided in the answer section is 1-0.1754=0.825 which gives me no clue whatsoever. Why is it 15.5 anyway?

Comment: Oh I see it seeks the value for z and since its approx it cannot be exactly the same. Are you able to figure out method used in the answer though?

Comment: @user154336 $\mu=np = 18$ and $\sigma=\sqrt{np(1-p)}=\sqrt{7.2}$, which gives
$$\frac{15.5-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}\approx-0.93169499062.$$
And Excel calculates the probabilities
$$P(Z\color{red}<-0.93169499062)\approx0.175747088,\\
P(Z\color{red}\ge-0.93169499062)\approx0.824252912;$$
and these are of course slightly off depending on significance in your $Z$-table and whether you do a linear interpolation. Otherwise, by doing the summation, Excel gives 
$$\sum_{k=16}^{30}{30\choose k}.6^k(1-.6)^{30-k}=0.824630946.$$

Comment: How do I apply this summation without excel or anything?

Answer (score 0):

You have everything to solve the problem. What you need is

$$
P( X \geq 16) = \sum_{k=16}^{n} \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^k
$$
which is trivial given you have both $p$ and $n$.

EDIT for the second problem, think about this: in how many ways can you get $10$ from $0,1,2,3,4$ with three samples with replacement? It's either one $2$ and two $4$ or two $3$ and one $4$. Obviously, the order doesn't matter. Can you find the probability now?

Comment: Hmmm... not the correct distribution, I am afraid.

Comment: Fixed. This is the solution to the first problem.

Comment: So I gotta do combination for each value in the first one?